# Highcharts column color

Tags: charts, highcharts

i'm building some charts using Highcharts

My problem is:

My attribute "size" on pie chart is already 100%. My div's height and width are 234 and 424px, but the pie is really smaller and doesn't get any bigger than 130px for both attributes...

Is there any properties that i could use?

Thanks

UPDATE:

OK guys, found the answer, i got a newer version of the highcharts plugin, the only problem is that my column chart is black lol, any ideas?

UPDATE 2:

My code to column's chart is:

//The colorBar parameter modifies just the 'hover' of the bars

```
function graficoBarraSimples_init(paramX, paramY, colorBar, container, title)
{
var options = 
{
    chart: {
        renderTo: container,
        defaultSeriesType: 'column'
    },
        title: {
        text: ''
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },

    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Unidade'
        },
        tickPixelInterval: 50
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '' + this.x +': '+ this.y ;
        }
    },
    xAxis: [],
    series:[]     
}

var i = 0;
var items = paramY.split(',');
var itemX = paramX.split(',');

var series = {
    type: 'column',
    color:[],
    data: []
};
var xAxis = {
    categories: [],
    title: { text:title}
};

$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
    series.name = itemX[itemNo];
    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
    series.color.push(CorValor(colorBar));          

    i++;
});

xAxis.categories=  itemX;
options.xAxis.push(xAxis);
options.series.push(series);
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

  }
```

**FINAL UPDATE**

Guys, found the problem again.
Aparently, Highcharts doesn't accept the 'injection' or 'push' to the graph's color, as is this line:

`series.color.push(CorValor(colorBar));`

So, i just changed the 'series' property directly:

```
    var series = {
    type: 'column',
    color:CorValor(colorBar),
        data: []
};
```

And excluded the `series.color.push(CorValor(colorBar));` line.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the highchart declaration her so we can help you better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, the last problem is that in the following object the color must be a string:

```
var series = {
    type: 'column',
    color:[], // change to color:'',
    data: []
};
```

And then you have to set instead of push:

```
$.each(items, function(itemNo, item) {
    series.name = itemX[itemNo];
    series.data.push(parseFloat(item));
    series.color = CorValor(colorBar);          

    i++;
});
```

Comment: Yes, this was exactly the problem. Thanks !